# Flutter web local storage issue with Getx

Tags: flutter, local-storage, flutter-web, flutter-getx

I have a question. After logging in, I save the token with get storage, then when I redirect to a new page with the url launcher, the existing token is lost and sometimes I get this problem and sometimes I don't. Below is how I write and read get storage

```
{
  final box = GetStorage();
  box.write("token", nvResponseLogin.value.auth!.token);
}

{
      final _box = GetStorage();
      String? token = _box.read("token");
      if (token == null) {
      token = "";
      }
}
```

Comment: Why use _box inplace of box?

Comment: I made a mistake while posting the code. Sory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Basically it seems your code is not wrong.
2. Make sure variable is 'box' or '_box'.
3. Check the right token is saved or not before use.
   ex) print token right after saving the token to getStorage.

Comment: If the reason for your 2nd item is due to my codes lying wrong, in your 3rd item, yes, I did my checks at every step and there is nothing wrong.